# python requests login post get response code 500

Tags: python, python-requests

```
code below:
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import requests

#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',"ContentType":"text/xml;charset=utf-8"}
payload = {
    'userName':'myusername',
    'password':'mypasswd',
    'callback':'jQuery17209257929018213263_1425826216682',
    'redirectURL':'http://www.10010.com',
    'redirectType':'01',
    'productType':'01',
    'pwdType':'01',strong text
    'rememberMe':'01'
}
link    = 'https://uac.10010.com/portal/Service/MallLogin'
s = requests.Session()
resp    = s.post(link,data=payload)
print resp
print resp.content
print resp.text
```

when i run the code ,i get the response 500,but when i copy  this link with params in the browser,it works and i could login.
i cannot find the reason .i need the help,thanks!

Comment: There are many reasons why this could fail. For example, the login page may require some cookies to be set before making the login attempt. Or there might be some other request header that you are missing.

Comment: Response code `500` means a server side error. Do you get back any information on the error page send from the server? Do you have access to the server and can check with the log files of that server?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
header_content = {'Content-type': 'application/json'} 
js_data = json.dumps({'username': 'myusername', 
             'password': 'mypasswd',
             'callback':'jQuery17209257929018213263_1425826216682',
             'redirectURL':'http://www.10010.com',
             'redirectType':'01',
             'productType':'01',
             'pwdType':'01',
             'rememberMe':'01'})
response = requests.post(link, data=js_data, headers=header_content, verify=False)

if response.status_code == 200:
   print(response.content)
```

You need to specify content in the header, in your case it is json. Also, as you perform a request through https, certificate verification could cause a problem, so turn the verification off by "verify=False". Also error in json format could be a reason of 500, so to be sure that you are passing appropriate json object, I recommend to use json.dumps().
Hope it helps. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

when you get this error, first check to see if your webpage can be loaded in a browser or not ...

> localhost/codeigniter_folder_name/index.php

it may shows some errors about permission. In this case, change the permission of your codeigniter folder with this command:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/Codeigniter_folder_name
```

Comment: The question is about connecting to a remote site, not debugging a local php site.

Comment: I got the same error and i found that my php site doesnt work neither locally nor remote. I put my site on raspberry and it doesnt work (but it works on windows OS). Then i figure out this was because of a permission problem in linux OS